Char code is different between .NET 4.8 and .NET 6
Previously with VB.NET (.NET 4.8) I have read files with the encoding windows-1252 in that way:
File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))

Now in my ASP.NET Core 6 application I'm reading the same file with the same code converted to C#:
 File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

For a special char inside the file VB.NET returns char-code char = 132 and ASP.NET Core 6 returns char = 8222. Why is the code different and how can I fix it?
I have already followed this question. I have added the package and registered the provider, but this doesn't change anything - it the same behavior with or without.

How certain are you that Encoding.Default really is Windows-1252? If you change your VB code to use Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) what happens? (Or if you use Encoding.Default in the C# code.) What character do you expect it to be?

Expected is char = 132, I have changed VB-Code as suggest to My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")). VB-Code returns 132 and .NET 6 return 8222

I have changed the question, to explain the issue better.

It doesn't explain anything because there's no actual text to check, something that actually reproduces the problem. Char is a Unicode character in all .NET versions and the decimal 132 is the unprintable IND control code while the hex 132 is the Ĳ character. The character with decimal code 8222 is „.

No matter what language or .NET platform you use, the Unicode value of „ is 8222, because Char is Unicode. This isn't up to debate. I don't know how you got 132, but I suspect that somehow you tried to get the ASCII value in a specific codepage, instead of the actual code. That's just wrong.

No repro, as expected. As this fiddle shows Console.WriteLine((int)'„'); prints 8222. In VB.NET Console.WriteLine(AscW(c)) prints 8222. If you use Asc, you have a bug and never got the actual code at all. You got the code after converting the character to the encoding corresponding to the current thread's culture. That would be a bug even in VB6, all the way back to the 1990s - VB strings were Unicode too

Why do you care about 132 anyway? What's the actual problem you want to solve? You don't need to know the numeric value of a character to search for it, replace it or split. var items=someLine.Split('„'); works fine. someLine.IndexOf('„') also works

Ok I havn't thought about that unicode thing. That explains the issue... I have ported a code from VB.NET to C# which was written before 2010. In the old days my colleagues have converted a special DOS coding page with german umlaut manually by comparing the chars with Chr(XX), which obviously has worked. After porting to C# it hasn't worked anymore in that way, because of this I have checked the char-codes. Anyway I was able to find the right DOS coding page to read the file with the correct encoding and I don't need a converting anymore. Thanks for your suggestions.

I'll assume that you once wrote a file indicating the Default encoding. And on the system where it happened, it wasn't 1252.
